# Omnipresent is to Ubiquitous as Omnipotent is to _____?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

"Omnipresent" means everywhere at once, while "ubiquitous" means *seeming* to be everywhere at once. My question is whether "omnipotent" (all-powerful) has a similar *'seeming to be all-powerful'* counterpart.

Comment: Omnipresent connotes a single entity that is everywhere at once.  Ubiquitous usually is used when many instances of a thing can be found everywhere.  And I think the "seemingly everywhere" is just using ubiquitous as an exaggeration, which is often the case because there aren't many things, if any, that are truly ubiquitous.  I think power is fundamentally different than presence and thus doesn't have an analog in your case.  Omnipotent itself can be used in a sarcastic and exaggerated way though.

Comment: Ubiquitous: having or seeming to have the ability to be everywhere at once; omnipresent. Collins  Dictionary

Comment: Please include the research you've done.

Answer (score 5):

According to M-W, *[ubiquity](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ubiquity)* **is** [*omnipresence*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/omnipresence?show=0&t=1400820410). The distinction you're making doesn't exist for the noun forms.

For the adjective *[ubiquitous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ubiquitous)*, it's interesting to note that, while the free version of M-W (at the link) gives the "seeming to be seen everywhere" definition, the Unabridged version does not:

> **ubiquitous**, *adj*.: existing or being everywhere at the same time :  occurring or capable of appearing everywhere or in many places
>   throughout a particular area, sphere, or production :  omnipresent

So to fill in the blank, any synonym of *omnipotent* that pleases your ear will do. I would suggest *[puissant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/puissant)*:

> *Omnipresent* is to *ubiquitous* as *omnipotent* is to *puissant*.

Answer (score 1):

Before the word pluripotent was used in biology, I believe that it had a meaning similar to what you're looking for. A pluripotentate was a person with almost all the powers of a potentate (ruler), frequently acting as an ambassador. It is old usage and I cannot find it on the web because of all the 'hits' in biology.

Answer (score 1):

[Ubiquitous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Ubiquitous):

> - adj -  having or seeming to have the ability to be everywhere at once; omnipresent.

I can find no evidence that support your view on the  distinction in meaning between *omnipresent* and *ubiquitous*, they appear to be close synonyms.

As for *omnipotent* , I suggest **[almighty](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/almighty)** as the best synonym I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Though they are considered to be close synonyms , I have mostly seen Omnipresent being used for God , people or as far as I can think 'Laws' . 'Ubiquitous' on the other hand can be used for any thing, shops , flowers anything that you can find scattered over a place wherever you go. Omnipresent generally holds strong meaning.

I tried but could not get a word that you are looking for 'seeming to be all-powerful' counterpart nor am I sure where would such a word be used.

Closest I could go to is Almighty, Mighty.

Answer (score 0):

That's what a thesaurus is for:

omnipotent
adjective
the worship of omnipotent deities: all-powerful, **almighty**, supreme, preeminent, most high; invincible, unconquerable.

I vote for almighty. Which is almost a literal translation of omnipotent.

Omni = all
potent --> powerful --> mighty